# My row inside a col dont get all height possible

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dTbl.jpg)My row dont get the height remaining of my col

```
<div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="col-lg-8 pt-4"><div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="row"><div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="col-lg-6"><app-chart-verba _ngcontent-aub-c22="" _nghost-aub-c19=""><div _ngcontent-aub-c19="" class="bg-secondary text-center rounded p-4"><div _ngcontent-aub-c19="" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4"><h6 _ngcontent-aub-c19="" class="mb-0">Verba da Semana x Verba Utilizada</h6></div><div _ngcontent-aub-c19=""><canvas _ngcontent-aub-c19="" basechart="" class="chart-bar" ng-reflect-datasets="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-labels="semana 1,semana 2,semana 3,sem" width="395" height="197" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 246.25px; width: 493.75px;"></canvas></div></div></app-chart-verba></div><div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="col-lg-6"><app-chart-termometro _ngcontent-aub-c22="" _nghost-aub-c20=""><div _ngcontent-aub-c20="" class="bg-secondary text-center rounded p-4"><div _ngcontent-aub-c20="" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4"><h6 _ngcontent-aub-c20="" class="mb-0">Verba da Semana x Verba Utilizada</h6></div><div _ngcontent-aub-c20=""><canvas _ngcontent-aub-c20="" basechart="" class="chart-bar" ng-reflect-type="bar" ng-reflect-datasets="[object Object]" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-labels="Red,Green" width="395" height="197" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 246.25px; width: 493.75px;"></canvas></div></div></app-chart-termometro></div></div><div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="row"><div _ngcontent-aub-c22="" class="col-lg-12 pt-4"><app-chart-verba-diaria _ngcontent-aub-c22="" _nghost-aub-c21=""><div _ngcontent-aub-c21="" class="bg-secondary text-center rounded p-4 h-100"><div _ngcontent-aub-c21="" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4"><h6 _ngcontent-aub-c21="" class="mb-0">Worldwide Sales</h6></div><div _ngcontent-aub-c21="" class="w-100"><canvas _ngcontent-aub-c21="" basechart="" class="chart-bar" ng-reflect-type="bar" ng-reflect-datasets="[object Object]" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-labels="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13," width="849" height="120" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 150px; width: 1061.25px;"></canvas></div></div></app-chart-verba-diaria></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you cut your code down a bit to make it easier to find the problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example